# Aerodynamic design and characteristic of fan vs blower

Tags: aerodynamics, compressors, turbomachinery, fan

I just learnt about the difference between a fan and a blower, namely the former providing high flow rate at very low outlet pressure (<1.1*inlet) and the latter providing a slightly increased pressure with less flow rate. I was a bit surprised that it was just this considered the **very** different design of the two.

So I was interested in understanding some more: could someone explain me why there is such a difference in the aerodynamic design (fans having very few blades but quite big, axial flow, blowers a lot of small blades, centrifugal/mixed flow, diffuser...)?

Also, at university the course of thermal machines taught me that turbocompressors have a characteristic curve like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Conventional-compressor-characteristic-for-a-large-turbocharger-compressor-as-measured-on_fig1_239407459): do fans and blower have an analogous one?

Comment: Fans and blowers do not have hard definitions, there are several designs of each to consider and overlap in the middle.

Comment: Fan blower compressor... There's an optimization problem in there somewhere that applies to wind turbines and fans that provides the most effect from 3 blades due to structure (to bear axial loads) and area that each blade applies to with large axial flow.  With outward radial flow, you get the natural effect of a diffuser  (opposite of a nozzle) building up pressure via reduction of velocity and increased area. I somehow feel like I answered something like this before...